# Identifying this connector

Tags: ac, connector, identification

Can anyone identify this connector? Found inside a Panasonic fan.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please be aware that shopping questions get closed quite quickly. See the Help Center for rules.

Comment: This is not a shopping question - I am just trying to ID this connector

Comment: From your question: "*A Digikey link would be awesome.*"

Comment: Yes but that is not the main purpose of the question. I added that in case someone answering decided to put a link to a specific supplier

Comment: These skinny little connectors tend to be proprietary.

Comment: Measure the blade width and pitch. That might aid your search but there's a good chance it's proprietary. In that case, it's most often just the plastic which is propriety and the blade/contacts are standard if you can consider some DIY.